# Python3 initiating problem

Tags: 18.04, python3

I use Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS. When I try to start python IDLE, it looks as if it's starting but doesn't start.

After investigating I noticed that there is a python app running in system monitor along with Python 3.6. When I kill the python program, Python 3.6 starts.